# Azure fails to deploy ASP.NET Core app / Can't connect to MyGet server

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, nuget-package-restore

I'm somewhat new to .NET Core and I'm trying to make a RESTful web api with authentication (using OpenIddict as the middleware). I working with Visual Studio Code on OSX.

To use OpenIddict, I have to add another source for the packages so following the tutorial, I added a NuGet.config file at the root of my project which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="aspnet-contrib" value="https://aspnetcontrib.myget.org/F/aspnet-contrib/api/v3/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

So I restore, I build, I run, I try it with Postman... Nice! Everything works. So, I tried to push it in Azure. So I set up an app, configure it source as local Git, and I push my app. Good.

Then, Azure tries to build it but fail when running the deployment command, which is when (I suppose) it fetches the package and all, right? Well, the error is that:

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj...
  Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj...
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.secretmanager.tools/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.runtime.coreclr/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.dotnethostpolicy/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.csharp/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.codeanalysis.visualbasic/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.platformabstractions/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.data.sqlite/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/libuv/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegeneration.tools/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/aspnet.security.oauth.validation/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.app/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.platforms/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.visualbasic/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/nuget.frameworks/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/runtime.native.system.io.compression/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    A connection with the server could not be established
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/runtime.native.system.io.compression/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
    A connection with the server could not be established
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'runtime.native.System.IO.Compression' from remote source 'https://myget-2e16.kxcdn.com/artifacts/aspnet-contrib/nuget/v3/flatcontainer/runtime.native.system.io.compression/index.json'. [D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   An error occurred while sending the request. [D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj]
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\1.0.1\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   A connection with the server could not be established [D:\home\site\repository\BobWebApi.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore "BobWebApi.csproj"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\62.60515.2845\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

So I don't know what to do. Why is Azure even trying to get all these files from the wrong source? And if I have to, how do I tell it where to get them?

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3065  that thread may be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I managed to solve everything by rebuilding, redeploying everything from scratch. I didn't find solution to quickly solve it, but since I was only beginning, it was no big deal. Just hope it won't hit me again.